# How can I use Apache Beam TestPubSub for unit testing

Tags: java, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to unit test a Java Apache Beam pipeline. I wanted to try and use the org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.pubsub.TestPubsub class (https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.7.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/TestPubsub.html) as it looks like it will enable topics to be created and destroyed within tests.

I am however unsure how this works, is it going to create an in memory pub sub instance for my tests? Or does it require me to either have a project connected to it or the pubsub emulator running in my local environment? Has anyone had any experience with using this and would they be able to provide me with any guidance/examples of how they have used it?

I ask this because at the moment I have a rule defined (detailed below) and when running my test it breaks while initialising the rule with the exception "com.google.api.gax.rpc.PermissionDeniedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: PERMISSION_DENIED: User not authorized to perform this action.".

```
@Rule
public TestPubsub testPubsub = TestPubsub.create();
```

Comment: For anyone who may come across this in future, I am still unsure on the use of TestPubsub but in the end changed my approach and used TestStream instead to simulate an unbounded source to then test other processing steps.

Answer (score 0):

According to @GradviusMars, instead of TestPubsub class, [TestStream](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.1.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/testing/TestStream.html) has been used to simulate an unbounded source to then test other processing steps.

Posting this as a Community Wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Please edit this if enhancement for the answer is needed.